# there is no output when the code is ran, how can i fix this?

Tags: javascript

there is no output to the code even tho it is being called at the bottom. How can i fix this?

```
 <script>
function hasMatch(item) {
    function inList() {
        var List = [1,2,3,4];
        for (i = 0; i<List.length; i++){
            if (List[i] = item) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    inList();
}
hasMatch(2);
hasMatch();
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you define a function inside a function and then call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do like this:

```js
function hasMatch(item) {
    function inList() {
        var List = [1,2,3,4];
        for (var i = 0; i<List.length; i++){
            if (List[i] == item) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return inList(item);
}

console.log (hasMatch(2));
```

Comment: tried it, still no output, maybe my working out of the code is wrong?

Comment: @sharjeel, add smth like `console.log (hasMatch (2));`

Comment: @sharjeel you also has a problem with a return statement inside the `inList` method, b/c it drops a cycle if item != 1

Comment: @sharjeel and I forgot to notice about condition, b/c operator `=` returns `true` each time... change it to `==` or `===`. In other way even `hasMatch (7); // true`

Comment: that works perfect, thanks friend! and about the operators, i'll keep that in mind!

Answer (score 3):

You need to `return` the output of `inList`

```js
function hasMatch(item) {
    function inList() {
        var List = [1,2,3,4];
        for (i = 0; i<List.length; i++){
            if (List[i] = item) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return inList();
}
console.log(hasMatch(2));
console.log(hasMatch())
```

Comment: tried it, still no output, maybe my working out of the code is wrong?

Comment: @sharjeel This works. Click the `Run code snippet` button.